# How to inject/access angular $scope service object in Asp.Net MVC view

Tags: angularjs, razor, angularjs-scope

I am new to AngularJS but have some working knowledge with Asp.net MVC. Right now I am stuck in a problem, where I need to access AngularJS's $scope object inside a javascript block, in a MVC view.

**My Code:
--------**

```
<script>

    var mode = "@ViewBag.Mode";

    if (mode == "Edit") {

        var riskJSON = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ViewBag.RISKS));

        $scope.riskrefno = riskJSON.RiskRefNo;
        $scope.enquirydate = riskJSON.EnquiryDate;
        $scope.insuredname = riskJSON.InsuredName;
        $scope.insuredaddress = riskJSON.InsuredAddress;

}
<script>
```

> with the above code, I am getting the below error: "0x800a1391 -
>   JavaScript runtime error: '$scope' is undefined"

Could you please suggest a solution on how can I inject $scope service object into a MVC razor view?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a razor person, so take this with a grain of salt. But `$scope` is really meant to be accessed only inside of angular functions where it is injected. In this case, it looks like it should be in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it is not very clear, to which html element is this scope associated with. Remember scope  has a constraint existence. The only scope that is available globally is `$rootScope`.

To access $rootScope from a global context outside angular, you need to use the `angular.element` function to get hold of your app root and then call the scope function. Something like:

`var $scope = angular.element('body').scope();  // this returns root scope`

This example assume you have added `ng-app` on body tag.